# Steps to check if data follows weibull distribution

Tags: statistics, weibull

I have a data that has two columns. One is  time to failure in hrs and the other is failure mechanism. What are the steps to identify if the data follows weibull distribution?

I am new to Reliability and trying to figure out the solution